# Passing a "boolean" field in JSON

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit2 library to handle my HTTP requests/responses. Since this library automatically converts a Java model into a JSON, I can't create a field called "boolean", because the IDE understands it as a type, not a variable.
Unfortunately the API that I'm consuming requires a field called "boolean" in a specific request. Is there a way to do it easily? Something like an annotation?

That's the model that I would like to create:

```
public class foo{
private String string;
private int number;
private boolean boolean;
}
```

I'm using GSON library.

Comment: It obviously depends on JSON library used ...

Comment: @Selvin i edited the question, i'm using gson lib. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `@SerializedName("boolean")` and different variable name

Comment: Interesting ... what if gson is not used? but jackson ... Then this answer is not valid ...